# Flashing when clearing and repopulating a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I am using a timer to update values in a ListBox. Every tick I do the following:

```
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string thing in thingys)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(thing);
            }
```

However, when it does this, the ListBox quickly flashes white (empty) for a split second and then shows the new data. Is it possible to stop this flash? It's really annoying, seeing as the timer interval needs to be pretty low (~100ms at most)

Comment: There are many solutions to this on the net. Check out Double Buffering, or ownerdrawing the list box. eg: http://yacsharpblog.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/listbox-flicker.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
listBox1.BeginUpdate();
listBox1.Items.Clear();
listBox1.Items.AddRange(thingys);
listBox1.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I still can't believe I didn't find that earlier!

Comment: @AndrewSun: You are welcome. BTW: You should use `AddRange` instead the `foreach` loop if possible.